# Why are RVR values reported in good visibility?

Tags: metar

I just pulled the METAR for KLAX. Why are they reporting an RVR value for runway 25L if visibility is 9 statute miles?

KLAX 281553Z 00000KT 9SM R25L/2400VP6000FT FEW012 FEW045 18/08 A3000 RMK AO2 SLP157 FU FEW012 FU FEW045 T01780083 $

Comment: Because it's an automated system, so it follows a standard format... And it looks like it needs servicing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but RVR is usually not reported at KLAX from what I've seen in the past.

Comment: It's possible that when the "I need servicing" indicator is there, it may report everything by default in case one sensor is bad.

Comment: RVR and visibility is not the same thing. Besides, in theory, the general visibility could be good, while the RVR for a specific runway could be bad due to a local fog patch etc. Depends on the placement of the sensors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It looks like that METAR was corrected to](https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/board?ids=KLAX&&format=expanded)

> KLAX 281553Z COR 00000KT 9SM FEW012 FEW045 18/08 A3000 RMK AO2 SLP157
>   FU FEW012 FU FEW045 T01780083 $

Note the **COR** for [corrected](http://www.moratech.com/aviation/metar-class/metar-pg5.html). The corrected METAR does not include RVR.

Including a screen grab of aviationweather.gov in case they dont keep the info up for a long time.

[image]